# Next.js “Text content does not match server-rendered HTML” React hydration error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am doing dynamic SEO using server side api call and next js gives me Hydration error like Text content does not match server-rendered HTML this.

I want to do dynamic SEO using server side api call and next js.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is exactly, but "content not matching" can easily happen if you generate random numbers in a component

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an issue. By mistake i have passed script tag in next Head tag ([next/head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head)). Which is not supported by nextjs and because of that next app is crashing while i was trying add dynamic SEO tags (meta tags). if we want to use script tag in Head. we need to use next Script tag ([next/script](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script)).

Reference Links:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head.
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script.